# How to find out if an event has fired in another event handler without the use of flags?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling

I have two events A and B.

I need to check in the event handler of B if the Event A was raised. I know I can do it using a flag but I have used so many flags so far for these kind of situations; and want to use an alternate strategy.

Comment: Raised when?  An hour ago?  Ever?  But yes, if you have a gazillion flags then you're doing it wrong.  Help us help you with a relevant example from your code.

Comment: no no . just before the call to B event handler , like described in the reply below...

Answer (score 3):

To me this sounds like bad design. If event of A was raised, it should have done something like modifying the state of some object instance. So if event of B is raised, by checking the state changes done by event of A, you should know if it was raised or not. If I am wrong in terms of bad design, then please post more information on your solution.

Example:

```
void eventOfA(EventArgs args)
{
    // modify application or whatever state like
    myAppContext.ChangeStatus(2);
    // or
    myWhateverInstance.DoStuff();
}

void eventOfB(EventArgs args)
{
   if(myAppContext.Status == 2)
       // eventOfA was raised
   else
       // eventOfA was not raised

   // or
   if(myWhateverInstance.DidStuff)
       // eventOfA was raised
   else
       // eventOfA was not raised

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you should reconsider the semantic of your events, and create another one.
   Say if you have MyApplicationExit and SaveMyData Events, and that you don't need to save everything when application will exit right after, you can indeed check in the SaveMyData Handler wether MyApplicationExit was called before. But a much better choice would be to create another SaveMyDataOnExit event that you send when you are exiting and user want things to be saved. No so much work added since you HAVE to differentiate each case.
2. All that booleans you need are for Events ? Because if the event handling of .Net doesn't fit you, you might also consider to write your own EventHandler for your custom events, defining the meaning of AddHandler, RemoveHandler and RaiseEvent. So you might create any complex relationship beetwenn events, like raising one event could automatically -or with a condition on the event arg- raise another event, or whatever suits better your needs.